# Protractor - get the text of a select menu option

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, end-to-end, e2e-testing

I am using protractor for my e2e testing of my app. However I am building an array of new values when updating a record to compare against the old values to ensure they were updated correctly.

One of the fields is a select menu and so I want to grab the text from the option to push into the array.

I am selecting the option using:

```
element(by.id(fieldName6)).click().then(function() {
     element(by.css('#' + fieldName6 + ' option:nth-child(2)')).click();
});
```

This is all working lovely. I now want to be able to grab the text, not the value, of that option to push into my array. I have tried the following:

```
newValues.push(browser.executeScript("$('#" + fieldName6 + " option:nth-child(3)').text()"));
```

which pushes `Promise::17234 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}`, and

```
newValues.push(element(by.css('#' + fieldName6)).$('option:checked').getText());
```

which pushes `[object Object]`.

Pretty stuck now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Protractor` and `WebDriverJS` are entirely based on the [concept of promises](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#the-webdriver-control-flow). `element(by.css('#' + fieldName6)).$('option:checked').getText()` would return you a promise which would be *resolved into an option text by the Control Flow*.

You may collect promises into the `newValues` array, but, when you would need real values, you would have to resolve the promises inside. I would use the `protractor.promise.all()` for that:

```
protractor.promise.all(newValues).then(function (resolvedValues) {
    console.log(resolvedValues);
});
```

Note that if you just want to assert the values in `newValues`, you can use `expect()` directly - it knows when the promise is passed in and would resolve the promise implicitly before performing the check:

```
expect(newValues).toEqual(["option 1", "option 2"]);
```

Comment: That's excellent, thank you @alecxe the `protractor.promise.all(newValues).then(function (resolvedValues) {
    console.log(resolvedValues);
});` did indeed resolve into a correct array of values as I wanted. Thank you so much!